# openwrt firewall - block a set of ip addresses from internet access

Tags: linux, firewall, openwrt

I'm running OpenWRT Attitude Adjustment r33556 / LuCI Trunk (trunk+svn9325) on my WNDR3800.

I would like to configure my firewall to:

1. Only allow a specific range of IP addresses to access internet, like my static IP's.
2. Also block IP's from internet access in my DHCP IP range, and redirect to a local IP web server.

Comment: Have you looked over the documentation here: http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/firewall ?

Comment: yes I have read it and tried several methods, still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the examples (or lack of examples) miss the required explanation, so it took me some time too. 
This example is what made it happen for me:
https://serverfault.com/a/675605/412955

the answer tells to install ipset, in addition to iptables program, this is doable through the webinterface of LEDE / OpenWRT. Then create a set called blacklist (`ipset create blacklist hash:ip hashsize 4096`),
tell iptables to match to that blacklist (`iptables -I INPUT -m set --match-set blacklist src -j DROP && iptables -I FORWARD -m set --match-set blacklist src -j DROP`),
and then to also add the ip address(es) to the blacklist-set you want to block (`ipset add blacklist 8.8.8.8`)